# Not changing rooms based on dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am currently working on a text based game where you move between rooms and pick up items in said rooms, until you get to a 'boss' chamber. I've gotten everything to print correctly thus-far, and gotten it to display if there is an item in the room or not, and what item it is, and what room you're in.

My current issue is it's not changing rooms based on user input. For instance, you start in the Sepulture. A user input of North should bring your location into the Barracks. However, it won't move me from the Sepulture.

My code is as follows:

```
def intro():
    print("You've finally awoken, my fallen Lord. Your kingdom, once great, is now simply ruins.")
    print("To restore yourself to your once grand ability, you must collect the Souls of the previous Lords.")
    print("You can navigate your decrepit domain by entering: North, South, East and West.")
    print("To collect the Souls, you can enter: collect (soul name).")
    print("-" * 30, "\n")

def main():
    while True:
        location = 'Sepulture'
        inventory = []
        my_dict = {
            'Sepulture': {'North': 'Barracks', 'West': 'Grand Entrance', 'East': 'Chapel', 'South': 'Ruined Town'},
            'Barracks': {'East': 'War Room', 'South': 'Sepulture', 'soul': 'Soul of a Warrior Lord'},
            'War Room': {'West': 'Barracks', 'soul': 'Soul of a Dragon Lord'},
            'Chapel': {'East': 'Sepulture', 'soul': 'Soul of Light'},
            'Grand Entrance': {'North': 'Great Tower', 'West': 'Sepulture', 'soul': 'Soul of a Lord of Men'},
            'Great Tower': {'South': 'Grand Entrance', 'soul': 'Soul of a Lord of Lords'},
            'Ruined Town': {'North': 'Sepulture', 'East': 'Chamber of the Lord of Cinder', 'soul': 'Soul of the Pygmy'},
            'Chamber of the Lord of Cinder': {'West': 'Ruined Town', 'soul': 'Lord of Cinder'}
        }
        print("You currently reside in the", location + '.')
        print("You currently possess the following: ", *inventory)
        if location in my_dict and location != 'Sepulture':
            print("My Lord, you've found the {}.".format(my_dict[location]['soul']))
        print("What would you like to do, my Lord?")
        move = input()

        if move in my_dict[location]:
            location == my_dict[location][move]

intro()
main()
```

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: You are setting the value of location to be Sepulture again at the start of every loop. Move that part outside the loop and it should work properly.

Comment: You have a typo:  `location == my_dict[location][move]` has too many equal signs.

Answer (score 2):

With just a little reorganization, this works:

```
def intro():
    print("You've finally awoken, my fallen Lord. Your kingdom, once great, is now simply ruins.")
    print("To restore yourself to your once grand ability, you must collect the Souls of the previous Lords.")
    print("You can navigate your decrepit domain by entering: North, South, East and West.")
    print("To collect the Souls, you can enter: collect (soul name).")
    print("-" * 30, "\n")

my_dict = {
    'Sepulture': {'North': 'Barracks', 'West': 'Grand Entrance', 'East': 'Chapel', 'South': 'Ruined Town'},
    'Barracks': {'East': 'War Room', 'South': 'Sepulture', 'soul': 'Soul of a Warrior Lord'},
    'War Room': {'West': 'Barracks', 'soul': 'Soul of a Dragon Lord'},
    'Chapel': {'East': 'Sepulture', 'soul': 'Soul of Light'},
    'Grand Entrance': {'North': 'Great Tower', 'West': 'Sepulture', 'soul': 'Soul of a Lord of Men'},
    'Great Tower': {'South': 'Grand Entrance', 'soul': 'Soul of a Lord of Lords'},
    'Ruined Town': {'North': 'Sepulture', 'East': 'Chamber of the Lord of Cinder', 'soul': 'Soul of the Pygmy'},
    'Chamber of the Lord of Cinder': {'West': 'Ruined Town', 'soul': 'Lord of Cinder'}
}

def main():
    location = 'Sepulture'
    inventory = []

    while True:
        print("You currently reside in the", location + '.')
        print("You currently possess the following: ", *inventory)
        if location in my_dict and location != 'Sepulture':
            print("My Lord, you've found the {}.".format(my_dict[location]['soul']))
        print("What would you like to do, my Lord?")
        move = input()

        if move in my_dict[location]:
            location = my_dict[location][move]

intro()
main()
```

However, if you're going to take this to its logical conclusion, you seriously need to consider moving all of the storyline into a text file that you read at startup.  That way, you can use your "Adventure Engine" with other stories without rewriting the program.  That's how the early Adventure games worked.

Comment: Thank you Tim, that does work! Should be able to figure out the rest.

Answer (score 1):

```py
location = my_dict[location][move]
```

Because you have written two equal to there like this `==`

Comment: Yes, but that's not the only reason.  See Adam's comment above.

Comment: You are right, just place that ```location``` var before the while loop.